# What is the translation of this sentence?

Tags: translation

> ややきつめの目つきをしているものの根は奥手で純情な性格。

Is this right

My translation is: even though here appearance looks serious she is still undeveloped at the core thus having an innocent personality

**

> ややきつめの目つき

**
What does it mean ?

Answer (score 2):

> 「ややきつめの目{め}つき」

やや　＝　少{すこ}し ＝  slightly

きつめ　＝　きつい (harsh, intense)  + め (~ish, on the ~ side)

The form is 「**Adjective Stem + め**」.

The confusing thing here is that this suffix め can also be written 目 in kanji.  Thus, we actually have two 目's in this phrase with only the second one meaning "eyes".

目つき = one's look or expression

Putting it altogether, we have:

> "A look/expression that is slightly on the intense side"

Finally, your interpretation of the sentence is actually quite good.

Answer (score 1):

My translation attempt is: At first glance, her appearance looks a bit stern, but actually she is just shy and innocent.

I believe your interpretation of the sentence has no problem at all.

ややきつめの目つき means she has somewhat sharp and stern eyes, basically describing her appearance as not very friendly-looking.

根は in this sentence means "essentially" or "actually," depicting her true personality in the ensuing segment 奥手で純情な性格.

奥手 more literally denotes "unsophisticated," but I believe it is more close to "shy" in the sentence.