# What is the meaning of 奥手 here?

Tags: translation, meaning

Ok ,so this is frome a mange where two couple have been dating for a while but did not hold hand,yet .

> 奥手すぎて手も繋げていない

So what does {奥手すぎて} means ?
I tried to look it up but did not found any thing beside that {奥手} means late bloomer .

Comment: It seems it has been already answered in [your previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/what-is-the-translation-of-this-sentence). It might not be the complete answer for what 奥手 means though, it seems more appropriate to this sentence than the "late bloomer".

Answer (score 2):

> 「奥手{おくて}すぎて手{て}も繋{つな}げていない」

「奥手すぎて」

means:

"too slow in sexual developement and ..."

The whole phrase, therefore, means:

> "They haven't (even) been able to hold each other's hands for being too slow in sexual developement."